# How to custmoize git.el's diff face in Emacs?

Tags: git, emacs, customization, emacs-faces

My Emacs is set to display text as black background on green text. The problem is when i do a diff using git.el the part at the top of the buffer showing changes starting with --- or +++  is showed using greenish color on green so i can't read i check git.el but can not seem to figure out which face is used to control this ?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the buffer, move point to the mystery face and type `C-u C-x =` (aka `C-u M-x what-cursor-position`). Emacs first tells you a lot about the character at point, but then also notes:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 diff-header
  fontified            t
```

So the face you are looking for is `diff-header`.